# What design pattern should I follow in React?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

I am creating about more than thousand `svg` elements. When it comes to remove, update or select a single element, it is very expensive in terms of time. Because when I remove or update a specific `svg` element, it `re-renders` the whole parent node with all the hundred and thousand of children within. Here is code to add element and rendering.

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      propsList: []
      };
   },
  addProps: function(props) {
    var propsList = this.state.propsList.concat([props]);
      this.setState({ propsList: propsList });
        },
  render: function() {
    var components = this.state.propsList.map(function(props) {
      return React.createElement('g', props);
        });
    return React.createElement('div', null, components);
      }
  });
  ReactDOM.render(
      React.createElement(App, null),
      document.getElementById('svg')
    );
```

Please suggest a `design pattern` which can solve my problem. So when I add or remove an element, the parent node does not have to `re-render` as it contains thousand of children within.

Answer (score 0):

You could try caching the rendering of the elements, if their rendering is really the part that is slowing down your app:

```
var App = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      cachedElements: [],
      propsList: []
    };
  },

  addProps: function(props) {
    var propsList = this.state.propsList.concat([props]);
    var cachedElements = this.state.cachedElements.concat([
      React.createElement('g', props)
    ])
    this.setState({ 
      cachedElements: cachedElements,
      propsList: propsList 
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return React.createElement('div', null, this.state.cachedElements);
  }
});
```

I did not remove the propsList from the state, which you should do if it's not used in the rendering of the component. You can either use a module variable or a component property, or just remove it completely if you don't need access to all items at once - but I guess you do need to access them if you want full CRUD operations.